# jquery autocomplete - save data to DB when list item is clicked (select event)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, database, jquery-autocomplete

i've read a lot about jq autocomplete, but it seems, there is no way to make an ajax request while the select event is fired. 
I will write the search query into an DB-Table only when the element is clicked.

Firebug shows the url in red`GET http://server.ccc/api/my/logSearchQuery?a=searchquery&b=11&v=0`

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    var results = [];
    var _request = null;
    $("#input").autocomplete({
        source: function( request, response ) {
            _request = request;
            $.ajax({
                  url: "http://dataserver",
                  dataType: "jsonp",
                  jsonp: 'json.wrf',
                  data: {
                q: GenerateSearchQuery(request.term)
                  },
                  success: function( data ) {

                    results = $.map(data.response.docs, function(item) {
                    return {
                          label: item.Name,
                          value: {
                              id:cid
                          }
                        };
                    });
                response(results);
                  }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            event.preventDefault();
            // ---------------- here is what i've tried, but it fails----------------------
            $.ajax({
                  url: "api/my/logSearchQuery",
                  type: "get",
                  dataType: "json",
                  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                  data: {"a": encodeURIComponent(_request.term), "b": results.length, "v": 0},
                  success: function(data){
                      console.log(data);
                  },
                  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                      console.log(XMLHttpRequest+ " : "+ errorThrown + " : " + textStatus);
                    }
            });

            if (ui.item.value != "searchAll") {
                self.location = "/list/"+ui.item.value.id;
            } else {
                $('#searchForm').submit();
            }
        }
    });});
```

The Ajax call works into the source event, but thats not the right place i think.
The ajax errors are empty.

Please help.

Comment: Is the  Server  script enabled to accept `jsonp` request or `crossdomain` requests ?

Comment: @dreamweiver The `ajax call` in the source event is working, so i think **crossdomain** is accepted. But **the problem is the second ajax call in the select event**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, i am a beginner;-)

The problem was, that the code under the ajax call...

```
select: function( event, ui ) {
        event.preventDefault();
        // ---------------- here is what i've tried, but it fails----------------------
        $.ajax({
            url: "api/my/logSearchQuery",
            type: "get",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           data: {"a": encodeURIComponent(_request.term), "b": results.length, "v": 0},
              success: function(data){
                  console.log(data);
              },
              error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  console.log(XMLHttpRequest+ " : "+ errorThrown + " : " + textStatus);
                }
        });
  //----------this part--------------- 
        if (ui.item.value != "searchAll") {
            self.location = "/list/"+ui.item.value.id;
        } else {
            $('#searchForm').submit();
        }
    }
```

gets fired during the ajax call is working (asynchronous).

So i've putted the this part into the `complete:` event of `$.ajax`

```
complete: function(xhr, status){
 if (ui.item.value != "searchAll") {
   self.location =   "/some    /"+ui.item.value.pflnr;
} else {
   $('#seachBar_searchForm').submit();
}
 }
```

now it works fine.

Comment: good to know you solved it urself, now lets close this question by Self Answering